# Construct parallel line equidistant from two other parallel lines - Euclidea on iOS challenge 2.8

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I bet you know this game, [Euclidea](http://euclidea.xyz) - if not I recommend it... 
although I'm stuck on level 2.8 which is different on iOS than other platforms for which there are already walk throughs available.

Here is the riddle -
"Construct a straight line parallel to the given parallel lines that lies at equal distance from them"

[image: This is the puzzle prompt]

I need to build using compass and ruler an equdistant line between  two parallel lines (the equidistant will be parallel to those two). I did it, but there's an additional challenge to do it with 5 moves in this order- 
Two circles and 3 lines. Obviously, it's possible to construct a perpendicular to the two parallel lines and then a perpendicular bisector for that one, but 5 steps is pretty tricky.
Is it even possible?! I'm breaking my head over this..

Good luck guys :)

Answer (score 4):

> **EUCLIDEA IOS PROBLEM 2.8 / ANDROID 5.7 | 5E SOLUTION REQUIRED**
>
> **Given** Two parallel lines ${a}$ (for 'above') and ${b}$ ('below'), separated by a distance $2D$.
>
> **Goal** Construct line ${m}$ (for 'middle') parallel to and equidistant from both given lines, *i.e.*, separated by a distance $D$ from both $a$ and $b$.
>
> **Constraints** Only an unmarked straightedge and a non-rusty collapsible compass (*i.e.*, a compass that, while on paper, can have any radius but which cannot maintain said radius when not on paper) can be used. Use only from the construction steps below a number of steps that together require just five elementary steps; the fifth step must construct the goal line itself.
>
> - Construct a point: 0 elementary steps (E).
> - Mark the intersection of two curves with a point: 0E.
> - Construct a new line (*or line segment or ray): 1E.
> - Extend a given line segment (*or ray): 1E.
> - Construct a circle (non-rusty collapsible compass): 1E.
> - Construct the perpendicular bisector of a line segment: 3E.
> - Construct a new line perpendicular to an old line: 3E.
>
> **Hints from Euclidea (including Twitter support)** A known 5E solution employs five elementary steps in the order: circle, circle, line, line, line. The first circle is twice the radius of the second one. Homothety is used in the known solution.

**SOLUTION** Please refer to the figure below. Apologies for not having labels on this figure.

1. Construct two arbitrary points $O$ and $P$ on $b$ separated by a distance $OP > D$ (just eyeball it) **[OE running total]**.
2. Construct circle $P(O)$ centered on point $P$ and with radius $OP$ **[1E running total]**.

   - $P(O)$ intersects $b$ at a new point $Q$.
3. Construct $Q(O)$ **[2E running total]**.

   - $Q(O)$ also intersects $a$ at two points $L$ (for 'left') and $R$ ('right').
4. Construct $\overleftrightarrow{OL}$ **[3E running total]**.

   - $P(O)$ intersects $\overleftrightarrow{OL}$ at $O$ and another point $M_L$.
5. Construct $\overleftrightarrow{OR}$ **[4E running total]**.

   - $P(O)$ intersects $\overleftrightarrow{OR}$ at $O$ and another point $M_R$.
6. Construct the desired line $m = \overleftrightarrow{M_{L}M_{R}}$, shown in yellow in the figure below **[5E final total]**.

[image: 5S solution to this problem]

**PROOF OF THE SOLUTION**

1. Given that $OP$ is chosen such that $OQ$ is larger than the gap $2D$ between the two give lines, there exist exactly two points $L$ and $R$ of intersection between $Q(O)$ and $a$.
2. Homothety is then used in this construction. First, we define a homothetic point ${O}$ on one of the lines, with $b$ used here without loss of generality. $Q(O)$ is constructed to have twice the radius of $P(O)$. Hence, taking $O$ as the homothetic point, also known as the center of dilation, we can view $P(O)$ as the half-fold 'dilation' of $Q(O)$. This means that every line through $O$ intersects $P(O)$ and $Q(O)$ at corresponding points, with the point on $P(O)$ half as far from $O$ as its corresponding point on $Q(O)$ is.
3. More specifically, the point $M_L$ on $P(O)$ that corresponds to the point $L$ on $P(O)$ can be found by intersecting $\overleftrightarrow{OL}$ and $P(O)$. Point $M_R$ can also be found analogously using $R$.
4. Homothety preserves parallelism. Therefore, line $m := \overleftrightarrow{M_LM_R}$ is parallel to both $a$ and $b$, as desired.
5. Given that the homothety involved here involves a half-fold dilation of $Q(O)$ to $P(O)$, we know that the gap between $a$ and $m$ is also half of the gap between $a$ and $b$. This is equivalent to saying that $m$ is equidistant from both $a$ and $b$, as desired. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

I contacted their support and they came back very promptly with following hint: "The 5E solution in level 2.8 uses homothety. The radius of the second
circle is twice the radius of the first one."

After googling and some 10 minutes I managed to solve it :) Let me know if you want me to post the solution here.

Good luck!